# Byte array to hex char array conversion

Tags: java, hex

My byte array is look like

```
 byte[] x = { (byte) 0xff , (byte) 0x80  };
```

how can i convert it to char array {char[] y } where:-

```
y[0]='f';
y[1] ='f' and so on
```

Comment: ... and your "and so on" means what? Presumably you don't mean that every element in the array is `'f'`, which is what it looks like.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to `{ 'f', 'f', '8', '0' }`?

Comment: @Thilo Why did you marked this as duplicate? The Question is about convert to char array. Convert to string is not equal convert to char array in java. Especially when it concerns the passwords.

Answer (score 11):

This should help you:

```
byte[] data = { (byte) 0xff , (byte) 0x80  };
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
```

Comment: That doesn't yield `{ 'f', 'f', '8', '0' }`

Comment: Well that wasn't specified so i assumed he wants to convert the bytes into their corresponding character values...

Comment: True. The question was clarified later.

Comment: Thanks Thilo for the links, sharing code worked for me .                     byte[] x = {(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x60};
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(x.length * 2);
   for(byte b: x)
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
   String s =  sb.toString();
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();

Comment: This is unsafe for passwords.