# How to convert parts of byte array data to float data type in android app

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am creating an app that receives Bluetooth data. The data is then stored in an byte array in which will need to be converted to float but not all the data.

Here is an example of the byte array after it is converted to Hex:

```
36 32 35 2e 30 30 20 00 4e 52 33 31 34 2e 30 30 20 00 cb b7
```

and that is 625.00 NR314.00 E

The values I need is 625.00 and 314.00

So basically 0 to 5th bytes, and 11 to 15th bytes since the array has a length of 20.

How am I able to traverse the byte array to grab the necessary bytes and then convert them to float?

*** Update1

This is the code I have so far, successfully able to convert the data and traverse the loop but now need to convert the data to float.

```
byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
String decoded = new String(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

char[] chars = decoded.toCharArray();
String numberString = "";
String numberString2 = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    numberString += chars[i];
}
Float(numberString);

for(int i = 10; i < 16; i++){
    numberString2 += chars[i];
}
Float(numberString2);
```

Comment: Hint: Decode the byte array first then use a loop to iterate through the array and grab the number characters (0-9 and .) for example `for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++){if(yourLogicHere){numberString += byteArray[i];}}`, then cast it to a float when done `Float(numberString)`

Comment: What should I decode the byte array to? I was able to grab the necessary bytes from the byte array but is there a way to convert the byte array to ascii before looping through the array?

Comment: You could try `String decoded = new String(yourArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` or something similar like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854837/byte-array-to-hex-char-array-conversion#28854932

Comment: Casting to Float(numberString); does not work for me. I have updated the code above

Comment: Oh right, you need to use the full decleration like this `Float yourFloat = new Float(numberString);` or you can parse it like this `Float yourFloat = Float.parseFloat(numberString);`

Comment: I did that but still have an error, it claims that numberString is not an statement. The numberString stores char values

Comment: There must be more going on with your code that you didn't include in your edit. Both methods in my previous comment work with JDK15.

Comment: I used float instead of Float, I guess that makes the difference